# Вычисление значения функции на промежутке с шагом

Tags: python

[image: задание]

Вот мой вариант решения. При выводе даёт столбец из нулей. Подскажите пожалуйста в чём ошибка:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
x=-3
xr=2
h=0.25
a=[]
while x < xr:
    if x > 0:
        k = 1
        fx = 0
        while k <= 5:
            fx += x^k
            k +=1
    elif x > 0:
        fx = (np.pi)^(3.5*x)
    print (fx)
    a+=[fx]
    x=x+h
a=np.array(a)
plt.plot(a)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Степень в питоне это `**`, а `^` - это и в питоне и во многих других языках `xor` ("исключающее или"), а не степень.

Comment: У меня нет слов... Спасибо.

Comment: И в `elif` у вас неправильная копипаста, проверьте условие. Вернее, там можно просто `else` написать, без условия.